# Set queryParams for different from default values in Angular

Tags: angular

In my 7 Angular's  app I have default params for filter in Component:

```
this.filter = {
    page: 1,
    limit: 10,
    language: 'en'
};
```

I need to save the data in queryParams only when they change (from the default data). For exaple, if data is

```
this.filter = {
    page: 3,
    limit: 20,
    language: 'en'
};
```

then ULR should be like this `/search?page=2&limit=20`.

But, for default data URL should be that `/search`

I think to compare the parameters with default data and if they are different, then set to queryParams. But this way seems to me wrong. Whether there are any ways to do it more cleanly and correctly?

Comment: You want the query strings to be set conditionally but don't want to compare the filter objects ?

Comment: I have several pages, where used a lot of queryParams. Comparing independently on each component is time consuming. When user click 'Search' and running `this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.routerAct, queryParams: filter}` I whant to save in queryParams only different values. I wonder if there are any standard ways of processing such algorithms in Angular.